# Nautilus - Connect to Server (nfs)

Tags: mount, nautilus, 18.10, nfs

I can't connect to NFS share using nautilus "Connect to server" in "Other Location". "Connect" button seems to be disabled. Didn't find any logs related to this.

[image: Nautilus]

Already tried `apt install gvfs-backends` from other answer but didn't work. Mounting using `mount -t nfs server.local:/srv/nfs /mnt` works but I'd like to do this using nautilus and without root permissions.

Comment: I also tried to add NFS location to Nautilus manually in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. But when i click the bookmark i get error message "Sorry, could not display all the contents of "nfs": The specified location is not supported".

Comment: Ubuntu broke this by omitting the `gvfs-nfs` package. Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1637988

Answer (score 1):

Since this has not been solved in any meaningful way, here's what I found:

First of all, you can navigate to an NFS server either through the "Other locations" tab or by pressing ctrl+l and typing in the location:

nfs://host/exposed/path

If you try that you can be met with the following error message:

[image]

That means that the server didn't allow the user to connect. Let's see what we have in the server logs:

```
ec 11 00:02:49 somehost rpc.mountd[45603]: refused mount request from x.x.x.x for /temporary (/temporary): illegal port 55520
```

The port number will be different because every request is made to a new endpoint. To fix that, do the following:

1. SSH to the server
2. Edit `/etc/externals`
3. In the options for the share you want to mount, add `insecure`
4. Reload the shares by running `# exportfs -a` (as a root user)

Done.

Normally, NFS connections on port higher than 1023 are not allowed. The `insecure` flag specifies that this share can be mounted insecurely (meaning on high ports).

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory for your username under `/media/`  and then a directory under that to mount you nfs share. Then add the nfs mount to `/etc/fstab`

eg:

```
 # mkdir -p /media/username/nfs_share
 # chown -R username: /media/username
```

and then add the following to `/etc/fstab`

```
server.local:/srv/nfs   /media/username/nfs_share   nfs    user,noauto    0   0
```

then restart gnome files (nautilus) and it should appear in 'other locations' as your what ever you called the mount point. in this case it would appear as 'nfs_share'

You may need to kill nautilus from the command line and then re-start it because it likes to background rather than exit when you close it.

```
pkill nautilus
```

Don't use the directory `/media/username` as the mount point because you may want other shares and udisks may want to mount something else in there at some point.

Comment: He did say he did not want to mount it manually, but through nautilus.

Answer (score -2):

This work for me. I went into nautilus and found /mnt/your_mount_here and dragged it over under my other drives and it created the bookmark automatically

Comment: This only creates a shortcut to the already mounted directory. I want to create a bookmark which mounts NFS folder automatically.